# Passing an object to constructor when using StructureMap 3

Tags: c#, constructor, structuremap, structuremap3

I have some `UserControl`s in my c# project and use `Structuremap 3` as my IoC container, when I want to access the `UserControl`s I use following code:

```
var uc = new UserControlFactory().Create<MyUserControl>();
....
```

and this is `UserControlFactory` code:

```
public class UserControlFactory:IUserControlFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : UserControl
    {
        return (T) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

It work fine when I have some `interface`s as my `UserControl`s constructor parameters:

```
public class MyUserControl:UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
    }
}
```

But now I want to pass an object through the `UserControl` constructor:

```
public class MyUserControl:UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl(IMyInterface myInterface,MyClass object1)
    {
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass parameter to the constructor as follows:

```
public class UserControlFactory:IUserControlFactory
{
    public T Create<T>(MyClass object1) where T : UserControl
    {
        return (T) ObjectFactory.With("object1").EqualTo(object1).GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure StructureMap to know what to use for the constructor arguments like this:

```
            c.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>().Ctor<Bar>(bar);
```

In your case, it would probably look more like this:

```
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            c.For<MyUserControl>().Use<MyUserControl>().Ctor<MyClass>(myClass);
```

This will use the same instance of MyClass for each MyUserControl, though. If you want greater control over what object gets used each time, then I'd go with ialekseev's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve such type:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl(IMyInterface myInterface, MyClass object1)
    {
    }
}
```

as StructureMap auto-wires concrete types (so you don't need to register *MyUserControl* and *MyClass*). All you need for this code to work is just to have *IMyInterface* registered:

```
c.For<IMyInterface>().Use<MyInterface>();
```

What error do you get when you try to resolve *MyUserControl*?

**Side note**

You can easily refactor this:

```
public class UserControlFactory : IUserControlFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : UserControl
    {
        return (T) ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

To use generic API provided:

```
public class UserControlFactory : IUserControlFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T : UserControl
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.